# Modding Morrowind

Tags: mods, the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

First of all, this is not the same of [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69468/how-do-i-properly-install-mods-for-morrowind).

I finally decided to buy Morrowind, even against all my personal opinions about old graphics games so in order to minimize this I'm researching, without success so far, about mods.

My question is, plain and simple, what is the proper way to install and manage Morrowind mods?

Maybe due its age, I'm having serious difficulty in finding good and detailed articles (with screenshot, preferably) about this matter. Not like I'm expecting to find something like S.T.E.P. for Skyrim, but, you know.

I already found some mods recommendations and so but I haven't found yet a detailed guide on how exactly apply them. I've gather informations, though. Informations that said modding Morrowind is "old-school style", which means, manually.

It seems there is no "Mod Organizer" for Morrowind, that keeps the install directory clean, but I would really like to know that there is something better than Nexus Mod Manager.

Comment: Reading both this question and the linked one, it honestly does seem like you're asking the same thing.  Why isn't it a dupe?

Comment: This does seem like a duplicate, and the answer to your question would be the Nexus Mod Manager. It's a great manager for mods for all different kinds of games and it makes installing and managing them really easy.

Comment: Well... it is disputable, but imo this question feels like "what other thing except the Nexsus MM can I use" while the other feels like" how do I make Nexsus MM work properly".

Comment: iirc the something awful forums has a good topic on modding morrowind, with a lot of info in the first post. Sadly SA periodically closes its forums to outside (non paying) viewers. Today is one of those days. And, you might need the archives upgrade to see it. (Full disclosure, im not a goon (goon = user of SA)).

Comment: I don't need exactly a personal opinion, mainly because such kind of topics are usually cannon-fired quickly. I just need a reliable, and for god's sakes well written, source of information. @Ids: I didn't understand a word of what you said. O_O

Comment: There is a website, something awful (http://forums.somethingawful.com/forumdisplay.php?forumid=44) that site has forums, and part of the forum is about games. They have pretty good guides usually about modding open world rpgs. (Like morrowind, oblivion, fallout etc). So I would look there.

Comment: Sadly something awful (SA for short), is a site where you need to pay to post on the forums. And some times you even need to pay to read certain subjects. (You get a vague message, and some sort of annoying movie clip with a kid and a window, etc). To read old posts (archived) you need to pay even more. So, if the morrowind topic has been archived you cannot read it. Is this a bit more clear?

Comment: http://forums.somethingawful.com/showthread.php?threadid=3430891 try this link. (currently it is not working for me, it redirects me to 'buy a forum account'. But in a few days it will work again for me). SA has a kind of bad reputation. (Like 4chan) but their game guides are usually well written. And a lot of the guides on modding are also not bad. So I hope that helps.

Comment: There are mod managers. Wrye Mash is probably the best and cleanest, but it has a steep learning curve.

Comment: Should the title be "Adding mods to Morrowind"? I thought you were implying you wanted to personally mod Morrowind yourself.

Comment: WHat you linked is a duplicate. Frank should flag this as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

[Wrye Mash](http://wryemusings.com/#WryeMash) is a very, very powerful modding and game tweaking tool I've used myself when I used to mod Morrowind a lot. It let's you modify your saves, it can try to repair your savegames if something is broken and so forth.

It's not like Mod Organizer for Skyrim, so you can't keep your data files clean (It's been a while since I used it, there might be a way to do it nowadays.) but it is by far the best mod manager for Morrowind.

It does take a while to learn, since it's a bit complex.